# Extracting sub-string up to a double underscore in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to extract substrings in a character vector up to a double-underscore i.e. "__"

For example, let's say that I have the following data.table:

```
require(data.table)
Temp <- data.table(Name = paste0(c("Max_drawdown__","Expectancy__"),
                                 "anything_else"))
```

The target output is as follows:

```
Target_output <- c("Max_drawdown","Expectancy")
```

I can achieve this using strsplit as follows:

```
Temp[,do.call(rbind,strsplit(Name,"__"))[,1]]
```

However, I'm keen to understand how to achieve it using regular expressions.

I've tried using 'str_extract' from the stringr package as follows:

```
require(stringr)
Temp[,str_extract(Name,"[^__]*")]
```

Which gets stuck at the first "_" in the "Max_drawdown" prefix that I'm trying to extract.

Can someone please help me with a regular expression solution and explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract everything until double underscore. Using `sub` you can do this as :

```
library(data.table)
Temp[, Name := sub('(.*?)__.*', '\\1', Name)]
Temp

#           Name
#1: Max_drawdown
#2:   Expectancy
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ronak!

Answer (score 2):

With the following regex you get all characters before two following underscores. [] is a character class and defines only allowed characters or [^] not allowed characters. [^__] does not mean not two following underscores.

```
^(.*)[_]{2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution Andre.
I'm also looking to have the "__" removed from the output.
Using your code, I have:
Temp[,gsub("__","",str_extract(Name,"^(.*)[_]{2}"))] 
...which will achieve it. Is there an easier way using regex to return the substring excluding the "__"?
Thanks
(not sure why the above has bolded part of my comment. It's not intentional! Also, the first part of the gsub has the double underscore, but it's not showing up in the comment for some reason)

Comment: @Phil Then you need a "regular replace" in R. Then the regular expression would be `[_]{1,2}`. I have no idea about R. In PHP it would look like this: `$string = preg_replace('/[_]{1,2}/', '', 'Max_drawdown__'); // Maxdrawdown`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a contributed package (`stringr`), base R can do it.

To extract the string before the double underscore:

```
Temp[, Name := sub("(^.*)__.*$", "\\1", Name)]
Temp
#           Name
#1: Max_drawdown
#2:   Expectancy
```

To extract the string after the double underscore:

```
Temp[, Name := sub("^.*__", "", Name)]
Temp
#            Name
#1: anything_else
#2: anything_else
```

Comment: Thanks Rui.
I'm actually looking for the component of the substring up to the double underscore (rather than the "anything_else" section of the string).

However, I can use the regex expression you've cited above though to pull the first part of the substring, and then potentially use gsub to remove the double underscore (see reply to Andre for what I'm referring to).

Thanks

Comment: @Phil Sorry for the misunderstanding, it's corrected now, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks for updating!